# LocationManager coordinates are Nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am attempting to implement some dynamic distances from certain events in my news feed of my app. In my model class I have a field of `distance` in which I want to set once I load my VC. I have a method called `parseData` where I call a method to set the distance field in my model class that takes in a parameter of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

**Error Message**: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is the snippet for that method:

```
func parseData() {
        DataService.ds.REF_LOBBYGAMES.queryOrderedByChild("distance").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            self.lobbyGames = []
            // Parse Firebase Data
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let lobbyGameDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let lobbyGame = LobbyGameModel(lobbyKey: key, dictionary: lobbyGameDict)
                        lobbyGame.calculateDistanceAway(self.currentLocation)
                        self.lobbyGames.append(lobbyGame)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

What I want to do is pass in the user's current location that way I can do the calculating inside the model class. However, the line `lobbyGame.calculateDistanceAway(self.currentLocation)`
 crashes because `self.currentLocation` is `nil`.

Here is my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        navigationItem.title = "Events Near You"
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(220, green: 220, blue: 220)
        collectionView?.registerClass(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellId)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(0, green: 171, blue: 236)

        parseData()
    }
```

And here is my `didUpdateLocations` delegate method:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.currentLocation = manager.location?.coordinate
    }
```

I don't understand why the LocationManager's coordinates are nil! How do I fix this? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried logging the  `locations` array passed in the method

Comment: The problem is is that parseData is hit before the `didUpdateLocations` method is even called, so the location field is nil still!

Comment: then you should call parseData in the `didUpdateLocations` method

Comment: I tried that also but `didUpdateLocations` isn't even being called. I set breakpoints and it just never enters the method.

Comment: then you should search on questions on why locationManager isnt working. other code isnt relevant to this question then

Comment: Well I have searched locationManager questions and I have all the information put in my `info.plist` and I have declared everything correctly... unless i'm missing something

Comment: Have you seen the popup that request the authorization ?

Comment: Have you set the simulator's Location setting to some other than None?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure location manager is initialzed and try locations array instead of manager object.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations.last!
    }
```

Comment: I did this but the `didUpdateLocations` method is not being called

Comment: have you added these keys in **info.plist** **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** & **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**

Comment: Also make sure you run the code on device instead of simulator.

Comment: @FahadAzeem Actually you can run it in simulator and set location from Xcode.

Comment: Yes dear, you are right but its better not to rely on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that when I added the information to the `info.plist` again, I needed to uninstall the app on the simulator and on my physical device. Once that happened, everything began working.